# VB.net Looped ReadLine stops after one line

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, variables, stringreader

Ok I have run into an issue trying to do a loop I have a variable that contains a list of servers and when i try to loop it only loops once and stops

I have part of my code below to try and give you an idea what i'm doing although I have removed any data that will point back to what company I work for.

First Part of code, gets a list of servers from the domain

```
Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("c:\windows\system32\dsquery.exe", "computer " & cnameodd & oservpath & " -o rdn")
        oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        oStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
        oProcess.Start()
        Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
            sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Output of sOutPut looks like this (shown in the code below via debug.write("servers: " & sOutPut)

```
"SERVERxafe01"
"SERVERxafe02"
"SERVERxafe03"
"SERVERxafe04"
"SERVERxafe05"
"SERVERxafe06"
```

Then I am trying to get the output to loop a command for each server

```
If sOutput = "" Then
                    Debug.Write("No Servers Found")
                Else
                    Debug.Write("Servers: " & sOutput)
                    Dim reader As New StringReader(sOutput.Replace(Chr(34), ""))
                    While True
                        Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
                        Debug.Write("Line is" & line)
                        If line IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim command As String = " user " & user & " /server:" & line
                            Dim pStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("c:\windows\sysnative\query.exe", command)
                            pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
                            pStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                            pProcess.StartInfo = pStartInfo
                            pProcess.Start()
                            Using pStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = pProcess.StandardError
                                sOutput = pStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
                                Debug.Write(sOutput & "Error " & command)
                            End Using
                            Using pStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = pProcess.StandardOutput
                                sOutput = pStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
                                Debug.Write(sOutput & "Output" & command)
                                Return sOutput
                            End Using
                        End If
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
```

In the code I have it trying to output what line it is currently processing by doing debug.write, however anytime i run this i only see the first line of sOutPut being used and no other lines being looped, so basically only output of debug.write("Line is :" & line) is

```
Line is : SERVERxafe01
```

So I never get it looped through the other servers>

I just write code to try and make my work a little more productive however I don't consider myself a programmer as I get frustrated easily and taking calls while concentration on code makes be a little edgy

So any ideas are welcome, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to find more information I found a post that showed different techniques to exit a loop, not what i was looking for but found something that caught my attention in the bottom using statement I had

```
Return sOutput
```

which exits the module so it was stopping the loop

so with modifications this is now working, i had to put the return statesmen in an if statement so that it only runs return if it gets the data that is needed

```
  Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim server = sOutput.Replace(Chr(34), "")
        For Each line As String In server.Split(vbCrLf)
            Dim command As String = " " & user & " /server:" & line.Replace(vbLf, "")
            Dim pStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("c:\windows\sysnative\quser.exe", command)
            pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            pStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            pProcess.StartInfo = pStartInfo
            pProcess.Start()
            Using pStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = pProcess.StandardError
                sOutput = pStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
                If sOutput.Contains("SESSIONNAME") = True Then
                    Return "Found on Citrix Server: " & line & vbCrLf & sOutput
                End If
            End Using
            Using pStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = pProcess.StandardOutput
                sOutput = pStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
                If sOutput.Contains("SESSIONNAME") = True Then
                    Return "Found on Citrix Server: " & line & vbCrLf & sOutput
                End If
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
    while true
    '
    '
    '
    '
    '
    End While
```

with

```
    Do
    '
    '
    '
    '
    '
    Loop While line <> ""
```

Comment: Tried this, getting same results, it is only looping once with the first line and stopping, debug still shows sOutPut has multiple lines but it only shows one loop being done with the first line.

btw using VB.net 2010